# htaccess URL rewrite rule for everything under a folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have looked but can't find anything that works. I have an old site that we have updated. They had everything under a folder called site under the root. Now all the customers who have this bookmarked I would like to redirect them, regardless of what is after the folder site (subfolders, files), to the main page of the new site instead of page not found on our new WordPress install. Any help appreciated.

Old URL: `http://www.oldsite.com/site/....` to new URL `http://www.newsite.com`

I have tried this to no avail

```
Rewrite Rule ^site/(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com
```

Thanks.

Comment: You, anubhava, so good (not joking, see your rep), are asking such question? Strange! **`;)`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} oldsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirects something like `http://www.oldsite.com/site/some-page.html` to `http://www.newsite.com/some-page.html` (the matching bit of the URI *after* /site/ gets carried over in the 301 redirect), but if you want to redirect everything for /site/ to the index root of newsite, replace the target in the RewriteRule to `http://www.newsite.com/` (remove the $1 bit).

---

EDIT:

> I actually write it wrong above. It is actually the same domain name. The question should read old URL mysite.com/site.... everything under this folder to just redirect to mysite.com

Then what you want is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or alternatively with mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/site/(.*)$ /$1
```

Comment: I actually write it wrong above. It is actually the same domain name. The question should read old URL http://www.mysite.com/site.... everything under this folder to just redirect to http://www.mysite.com

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all you need is this simple 1 liner rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^site/ / [R=301,L,NC]
```